# Custom total amount

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have in Opportunity custom field in grid that represent a custom price of product. I would like to auto calculate this in external field as in the case of total amount.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question so that everyone can help you the best way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Rollup or Caluclate Field. This will help you solve your business case with out of Box functionality.

I personally would go for Rollup Field for your use Case

Calculate Field [Example 1](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/customization/calculated-fields/)

[Example 2](https://www.quantacrm.com/2018/07/26/how-to-create-a-calculated-field-on-a-form-in-microsoft-dynamics-365-for-sales-crm/)

[Official Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/define-calculated-fields)

Rollup Field [Example 1](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2014/10/10/roll-up-fields-dynamics-crm-2015/)

[Example 2](https://stoneridgesoftware.com/working-with-dynamics-crm-rollup-fields-and-indirectly-related-activities/)

[Official Doc for Roll up field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/define-rollup-fields)

and Difference between Calculate and Rollup Field can be found [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/passiondynamics/archive/2018/01/24/calculated-vs-roll-up-field)